# Safemode and Openbasedir issues on centos + vestacp

Tags: php, apache, centos, cakephp-2.5

VPS (digital ocean provider) : CentOS 6.8 x64 
Admin: VestaCP

I am trying to rsync my sites from another server. Rsync goes fine.

When I try to reach the site (the new one, rsynced to this server), I got an error in my cakephp logs:

```
2016-07-21 22:09:28 Warning: Warning (2): curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in
```

I tried to disable openbasedir in /etc/php.ini by : openbasedir = none
I don't find any safe_mode in this php.ini

In /usr/local/vesta/php/lib/php.ini , safemode = Off and openbasedir = none

I still get the errors after a service httpd restart

What can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I found where the issue was.

The file to edit was:

> /home/admin/conf/web/httpd.conf

And I had to comment:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/xxx.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
```